# Reacting threads needing its OWN COPY of the std::shared_future that refers to the share state

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question about page 270 of *Effective Modern C++*, written by the Scott Meyers.

Line 5/6, He writes: "The only subtlety is that each reacting thread needs ITS OWN COPY of the std::shared_future that refers to the shared state, ..."

My question is:  Why are we obliged to pass a copy of the `std::shared_future` to each lambda function in each thread?  Whereas à priori, I don't see any problem to pass it by reference, such that there is a unique shared state that would be used by different thread?

I wrote a code adapted from the book of Dr Scott Meyers which works, even if I pass sf par reference.

Thus, is it possible to pass it by reference?

```
#include <future>
#include <vector>

std::promise<void> p;

void react(){}

void detect()
{
    auto sf = p.get_future().share();

    std::vector<std::thread> vt;
    int n=10;
    for(int i=0;i < n; i++)
    {
        vt.emplace_back([sf]{sf.wait();
        react();
                        });
    }

p.set_value();

for(auto& t : vt)
    t.join();


}

int main()
{
    detect();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass by reference, multiple threads are accessing the same instance of `shared_future`.  This potentially results in a data race and is undefined behavior.  If multiple threads access the shared state via their own copy of `shared_future`, the library makes sure that they are synchronized.

The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/get) on `get` says:

> It effectively calls `wait()` in order to wait for the result.

And the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future/wait) on `wait` says:

> Calling wait on the same `std::shared_future` from multiple threads is
>   not safe; the intended use is for each thread that waits on the same
>   shared state to have a copy of a `std::shared_future`.

Comment: cppreference, while generally reliable, is not an official source, and has been known to be wrong.